# How long to wait till I can declare "Mission Accomplished" after my german roach DIY control program?

Tags: pest-control

My mother, unfortunately, had german cockroaches and it wasn't too long before I had to sit down with her and tell her what we had to do. We located leak behind the fridge and corrected it and looked for other sources of water that may be feeding the cockroaches.

One of the best things we used to monitor the situation with the german cockroaches were "Catchmaster Glue Traps/Roach Monitors". These sticky glue traps helped us pinpoint the fridge as a possible resource for the infestation. Keep in mind, prior to this we focused heavily at our dishes and our sink as that is where we would see the most baby/adult roaches roaming around at night. But it was really the glue traps that showed us that they were moving from under the fridge to other locations in the kitchen. After repairing the fridge's water system and correcting the leak, we went to work with cleaning out the entire kitchen. Cleaning behind the fridge, the stove, under the sink, etc, etc. Then I placed gentrol Insect Growth Hormone (IGR) and a gel bait throughout the kitchen. I can't think of letting German Cockroaches getting out of hand at my mother's place as I know if you see a few nymphs the problem is likely worse than it appears so doing these steps with her were necessary.

In any case, our glue trap monitors have done a great job letting us know where the roaches roam around, catching them where they appear. Now its been a few weeks from the treatment and I just replaced the initial glue traps that had roaches with repurposed glue traps that had no activity. We are already falling into our old ways because we feel like we eradicated them but what would be a more scientific approach to knowing the infestation has been cleared. I was thinking waiting 3 weeks with the new glue traps and if they have no roaches trapped then most likely their populations are on the verge of annihilation. Is this a good approach?

Comment: Germain cockroaches?  Are they wearing lederhosen?

Comment: No they don't. They are notorious though.

Comment: check the compressor of the fridge. there may be a plastic container on top of it. put salt in this so any water accumulating cannot be drunk.

Comment: That's a good idea. Keep that water from sustaining them.